# Error Handling Tool for .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, error-handling

I've been doing some research on how to globally handle errors in my ASP.NET application. Can anyone suggest me a customizable error handling component to handle all .NET exception globally and log them in database(SQL, Oracle) and also send notification via mail/RSS feed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) (Error Logging Modules and Handlers).

Comment: Can we use ELMAH with all types of .NET application (Web Application, Window Servie, web Service) and what about compatibility with .net versions (1.1, 2.0 & 3.5)

Comment: Web Application and Web Service are just different types of ASP.NET apps, so ELMAH should work with these just fine. Regarding Windows apps (like Windows Services), I think yoy can use ELMAH, but you may need to add a couple of lines of code (and maybe make some config changes). Regarding support for different .NET version, standard compatibility rules should apply (as with any other alternative you would use).